# How to ensure a struct with a string array as a field would follow value semantics while assigning to another variable

Tags: c#, struct, variable-assignment

In [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/saxz13w4.aspx) it is mentioned that "*Structs are copied on assignment. When a struct is assigned to a new variable, all the data is copied, and any modification to the new copy does not change the data for the original copy.*"

I have struct which has a string array as the only field inside it.

```
struct MyVar
{
    private readonly string[] value;
    MyVar(string[] iVal)
    {
        value = iVal;
    }
}
```

When I assign one struct variable to another how to ensure the string array would be copied fully (deep copy) to assigned variable.

Comment: @Rakkun: I am trying to convert code written in a language which is developed in-house using visual parser to c# where it is expected follow value semantics.

Comment: @Rakkun, Could you please provide an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in C# because there's no way to intercept the compiler-generated code to copy the struct's data from one to another.

The only thing you can really do is to make your struct fully immutable.

That means:

- When you create the struct, make a defensive copy of any mutable reference types that you store inside the struct (such as the string array in your example).
- Do not pass your mutable reference type objects to anything that can mutate them.
- Do not expose any mutable reference types from the struct. That would mean that you couldn't expose the string array from your struct.
- Don't do anything to mutate any reference types held in your struct. So in your example, you couldn't change the contents of your string array.

That's a lot of limitations. The safest way is to never store any mutable reference types in your struct...

Anyway, to make your struct safer you can defensively copy the string array:

```
struct MyVar
{
    private readonly string[] value;
    MyVar(string[] iVal)
    {
        value = (string[])iVal.Clone();
    }
}
```

That particular example is now safe to copy because it doesn't have any way for the string array to be mutated. But as soon as you add any mutator methods or expose the string array via a property, or pass it to anything that might mutate it, you're back to square one.

If you want to make a "manual" copy of your struct though, you can do that via serialization.

It's just that you can't do anything about:

```
MyVar var1 = new MyVar(test);
MyVar var2 = var1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions. I wonder why you finally said "It's just that your can't do anything about:". Do you mean to say even after cloning the array in the constructor, the statement MyVar var2 = var1 would not copy var1 string array to var2 string array?

Comment: @Imran Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I meant that you can't protect against someone writing those simple lines of code to make a copy of the  struct, BUT you could write a method to make a deep copy of your struct and use that. It's just that you can't *force* people to make copies using such a custom method.

Comment: Thank you again. I love SO. A great place for beginners like me to learn how something should and should not be done.

Comment: I followed instructions and modified my struct but still the statement MyVar var2 = var1 resulting in var2 referring to var1 string array. var2 is not getting its own copy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Imran My answer was intended to say that you can't make it so that each struct gets its own copy. Rather, a workaround is to make it so that it doesn't matter if the structs are sharing data between them by making it immutable. (That's why I started my answer with "You can't do this in C#")

Comment: Ok...I got it now. Thank you.